# How to make :active style hyperlinks that are middle-clicked?

Tags: css

In 99% of all cases when I click a link, I do it with the middle mouse button instead of the left mouse button. This, in all browsers I've ever tried, causes the URL to open in a new tab without shifting focus to it, unlike the left click which "destroys" your current page and replaces it with the new page.

When using `a:active` to style hyperlinks, this only applies to when you left-click it for some bizarre reason.

For example, take this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active

The example on that page only styles the hyperlink when you left-click it -- not when you middle-click it. It uses `:active`. I use Pale Moon.

How do I make `:active` actually style hyperlinks that are clicked, even if the middle mouse button is used?

It confuses me why they would even make such a distinction, since both are the same "event", just with slightly different client behaviours as a result.

It's not an option to start left-clicking links.